# Proving $f\left(\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_i\right) = \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} f(A_i)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to prove that Proving $f\left(\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_i\right) = \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} f(A_i)$. Here is my attempt.

> Given $y \in Y$, we have:
> \begin{align*}
> y \in f\left(\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_i\right) & \iff \exists a \in \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_i, \; y = f(a) \\
> & \iff \exists i \in I, \; a \in A_i, \; y = f(a) \\
> & \iff \exists i \in I, \; y \in f(A_i) \\
> & \iff y \in \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} f(A_i).
> \end{align*}

How does this look?

Comment: looks good.${}$

Comment: My suggestion is to use $\exists a$ in second line also. This leads you to rule how to reorder  quantifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me write down little additional specification based on, that $(\exists x \in X)R(x)\Leftrightarrow (\exists x)(x \in X\land R(x))$:

$$\begin{align*}
&\exists a \in \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_i, \; y = f(a) \\
& \iff (\exists a)\Big(a \in \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_i \land y = f(a)\Big)\\
&\iff (\exists a)\Big((\exists i)(i \in I \land a \in A_i) \land y = f(a)\Big)\\
&\iff (\exists a)(\exists i)\Big(i \in I \land a \in A_i \land y = f(a)\Big)\\
\end{align*}$$
Now you can reorder/move/group existential quantifiers and logical and  and get 3'd line.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is completely correct.

Comment: This is more suitable as a comment.

Comment: @AnuragA I'd agree if this was a more advanced question but I don't really think there's any meaningful improvement to be made on OP's proof and thought it better the question wasn't left unanswered (and I don't think anyone else is really going to answer anything else... but I'd be happy to be wrong).

Comment: @AnuragA It is better to have it as an answer, so the asker has something to mark as accepted and show the matter is closed.

Comment: +1 This answered the question.